# Prove that $x^2$ and $x^3$ are topological conjugated on $[0, \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

As in the topic. I have to prove that the functions $x ^ 2$ and $x ^ 3$ are topologically conjugated. I tried to write it out by definition: $f (x ^ 2) = f (x) ^ 3$ and choose $f (x) = x ^ a$, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It's my beginnings in this field, so I do not have much experience yet.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: If $f$ is defined on $[2,4)$, then you can extend the domain of $f$ to $[2,\infty)$ following the rule $f(x^2) := f(x)^3$

Comment: So, we are looking for a homeomorphism $f : [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that $f(x^2) = f(x)^3$?

Comment: Other preliminary stuff: the function must be striclty increasing, $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: If $f$ is also differentiable (not that it needs to be, just presenting an observation), then $2xf'(x^2) = 3f(x)^2f'(x),$ and inserting $x=1,$ we have $2f'(1)=3f(1)^2f'(1)$, so we either have $f'(1) = 0$, or otherwise $f(1) = \sqrt{2/3}$ (which is absurd since we know that $f(1)=1$).

Comment: I think, the function is completely determined by its values on $(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can consider the function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ defined by
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{\log(x)^{\log(3)/\log(2)}}&x>1\\
e^{-(-\log(x))^{\log(3)/\log(2)}}&0<x\leq 1\\
0&x=0
\end{cases}$$

To find this function, can be useful to note that $x^2$ is topologically conjugated to $2x$ through $\log$ function and similarly $x^3$ is conjugated to $3x$.
Moreover $x\to x^{\log(3)/\log(2)}$ is a conjugation between $2x$ and $3x$.
More precisely, we have the commutative diagram below where $h(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x)|x|^{\log(3)/\log(2)}$

[image]

Comment: Very nice, Fabio! It's because of $3^{\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}} = 3^{\log_3(2)} = 2$.

Comment: And for $x\in (0,1)$, what about $f(x)=e^{(-\log(x))^{\log(3)/\log(2)}}$ ? Seems to work.

Comment: I put another minus sign to make $f$ a bijection.

Comment: Fabio: Sure. Fair enough. ;o)